# How to get iPad to reliably connect to raspberry pi AP?

Tags: wifi, vnc, headless

I am designing a car computer that is a simple readout and data logger using an OBD cable. I want to avoid buying a screen, so I am planning to generate a wifi network using an AP dongle I have, and then VNC into the Pi using my iPad. However, when I connect to the wifi network with my iPad, it seems to disconnect after only a few seconds. I am thinking this is because the Pi is not providing any internet for the iPad. Is there a way to get around this?

In short, can I trick my iPad into thinking there is working internet using the raspberry pi?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Not really sure what you are asking about? it is very confusing what you have wrote. Please try and re phrase the question or make a diagram so that we can understand you better.

Comment: Could be a power issue. The pi is having to draw more power to usb to connect the iPad and cannot provide enough. I would suggest using a powered usb hub.

Comment: @Jivings I don't have the ipad directly connect to the pi with usb. I want to connect it with wifi, but the iPad keeps disconnecting.

Comment: IIRC, Apple devices have some sort of check to make sure they can contact apple or something when they connect to a WiFi network ? Maybe that's what's causing it ?  
Check the forums, they had a thread on apple devices a little while ago.

Comment: Does it work if you configure an IP address manually?

Comment: @TheDoctor I realise that. When the iPad connects to the AP dongle **wirelessly** it will create more power draw on the Pi, causing it to kill the connection.

Comment: @Jivings I had the same experience with a USB wifi dongle and a power-supply that I thought was supplying 1 amp but it wasn't. When I replaced the power-supply it started working.

Comment: **1)** Check the power supply. If you are just connecting to a phone charge powered by the car battery, this will probably not work. **2)** Does you wifi setup work with other computers?. On creating a wifi hotspot [see here](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot). **3)** Temporarily remove all security (encryption keys etc) on the wifi, and set your raspberry pi to have a static IP address. There is a good guide [here](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/take-control-of-your-raspberry-pi-using-your-mac-pc-ipad-or-phone--mac-54603).

Comment: Another protocol to connecting and controlling the PI from an iPad: http://www.recantha.co.uk/blog/?p=3947

Comment: This is just a thought, but using an ipad just for a screen is like renting a Ferrari to push your Honda. With that said, you may consider your redesigning your design, as the ipad alone could have an app (you create) that has a data logger. If that is not an option, there are TFT screens for a fraction of the cost of an ipad (https://www.adafruit.com/products/1680). Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

There could be many things going wrong here, but this seems most likely to be a power issue to me, if USB dongle is draining too much power then the dongle will drop in and out every few seconds. Hope this helps.

Comment: and so connecting the Wi-Fi dongle to the Pi via a powered USB hub would be the solution...